# Unable to play/pause/seek with Youtube IFrame API

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

Using the iFrame API I'm unable to stop, pause, seek or set the volume.

We're loading the Youtube IFrame API correctly and it auto plays, but we keep getting this obscure error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object
at Bh.l.Aa (www-embed-player.js:formatted:4252)
at Bh.l.ab (www-embed-player.js:formatted:3544)
at Kf.bf.C (www-embed-player.js:formatted:2737)
```

The same code is used elsewhere and it works just fine. There's no error from Youtube and nothing complains UNTIL we try to play/pause/seek. It's so weird.

I tracked it down to this code block in a minified JS loaded by Youtube:
On line 4224 of the www-embed-player.js (un minified/pretty):

```
    l.Aa = function(a, b) {
    if (this.b[a]) {
        b = b || [];
        if (0 < b.length && dh(a)) {
            var c;
            c = b;
            if (la(c[0]) && !ia(c[0]))
                c = c[0];
            else {
                var d = {};
                switch (a) {
                case "loadVideoById":
                case "cueVideoById":
                    d = fh.apply(window, c);
                    break;
                case "loadVideoByUrl":
                case "cueVideoByUrl":
                    d = eh.apply(window, c);
                    break;
                case "loadPlaylist":
                case "cuePlaylist":
                    d = gh.apply(window, c)
                }
                c = d
            }
            hh(c);
            b.length = 1;
            b[0] = c
        }
        this.b[a].apply(this.b, b);
        dh(a) && Ng(this, this.ja())
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that you probably did not find the error in the minified youtube API code. If it works in one place in your code and not in another, try and figure out what is different between the two areas of code.

Comment: You would think so but in the console that's where the error comes from.

Comment: I understand that, but if variables are passed in incorrectly, it may cause an error in the Youtube API. That doesn't mean that there is a problem with the API, but it will look like the API's fault in the console. I would look at the surrounding code, as that is most likely the problem.